# How to add picture to User Account Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, pictures

How do I add picture to User Account Windows 10? I did not see any options in Control Panel

Answer (score 6):

Click on the Start button on Taskbar.

You should be able to see your Account name at the uppermost part of Start Menu. Right Click on your Account name. You see three options in a dropdown – Click Change Account Settings.

On the right you can see your present account picture. Click Browse button to change it.

[Source](http://www.howto-connect.com/change-account-picture-on-windows-10-easy-steps/)

> If you are using a Microsoft Account for authentication, the display picture will be taken from the account (so you would need to upload one to your Microsoft Account online). Also, if you haven't activated your Windows installation yet, you won't be able to personalise Windows - once the activation is confirmed, you will be fine.

[Source](https://superuser.com/users/354006/james)

Comment: If you are using a Microsoft Account for authentication, the display picture will be taken from the account (so you would need to upload one to your Microsoft Account online).  Also, if you haven't activated your Windows installation yet, you won't be able to personalise Windows - once the activation is confirmed, you will be fine.